# cross compiling sqlite for arm arm926ej-s

Tags: linux, sqlite, arm, cross-compiling, qemu

What i did is
Downloaded and extracted the sqlite
then on Ubuntu

```
$ sudo ./configure --host=arm-linux CC=arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc AR=arm-linux-gnueabi-ar STRIP=arm-linux-gnueabi-strip RANLIB=arm-linux-gnueabi-ranlib CFLAGS="-mtune=arm926ej-s -mfpu=vfp -Os -lpthread -lrt" LDFLAGS=${LDFLAGS}
$ make
$ make install  DESTDIR=/sqlite
```

then copied the usr folder inside /sqlite to the /usr inside qemu disk image
then booted the debian for arm on qemu

entered sqlite3 but this is what happened

[image]

*when i type sql + [tab] then it auto completes
*I did it as root, so not used sudo
*My reference was http://www.friendlyarm.net/forum/topic/1522#7386

Comment: Does `ldd /usr/local/bin/sqlite3` succedd in the ARM machine?

Comment: it says `/usr/bin/ldd: line 116: /usr/local/bin/sqlite3: No such file or directory`

Comment: So where is `sqlite3` actually installed in the ARM machine?